# Can not uninstall Windows Phone 8 SDK from Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-phone, sdk, windows-8.1-preview

Recently, I had updated my Windows 8 to 8.1, and got some errors with Windows Phone 8 SDK (I could not run unit tests).

The problem is that on Windows 8 I had installed WP 8 SDK with Russian language (my failure...), and now I am not able to uninstall it because it says that Windows running with compatibility settings and I have to disable them to delete SDK, but I do not know how to do it...

Comment: Unless you made a backup of your system from before you installed Windows 8.1 you will be unable to resolve this problem if either installing VS2012 Update 3 or VS2013 Preview does not resolve the problem.  You did make that backup right?  Your upgrade to the Windows 8.1 Preview is a one-way upgrade otherwise.

Comment: if you are doing anything with XNA then don't: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2012/12/18/10379045.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who runs in to this (since it's first hit on google):

Run the uninstaller from "Programs and Features", it'll fail and give this error.

Right click the icon (Red Visual studio) on the start bar, right click the app, properties.

Compatibility, Change settings for all users, Run this in compatibility mode for Windows 8.
[OK]

Right click it on the menu, and run it.

Worked for me :)

Answer (score -4):

You can install visual studio 2012 update 3 or upgrade to visual studio 2013 ultimate preview, which already has the windows phone 8 sdk inbuilt.

Comment: He's trying to uninstall the SDK, not install it.